# InstallShield Silent Install - How to check if its complete?

Tags: installshield

I am using [this page](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q101901) for authoring a silent installation using InstallShield 2012

How do I know that silent install is complete. is there a way to signal from InstallShield while doing a silent installation ? One way is to write an empty file saying 'Done' when installation is complete. But, I am sure there is a better way via the InstallShield itself.

Comment: Why do you need this? The solution depends a lot on what you need to do with the check result.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling to the installer ?

If you call it from another  program you can check the result code, must be 0.

If you call it from console you can check int Setup.log file [ResponseResult], or you can write a simple batch file to write the result code to another file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Console (CMD Prompt), then pass the install with appropriate arguments.

Ex:- If i need to install setup.msi silently and then need to know whether installation is complete or not, pass the following arguments in the CMD.

```
MSIEXEC /i setup.msi /qn+
```